# A regularity result for semilinear PDE of the form $\Delta u=f(x, u)$ in Michael E. Taylor's book "Partial Differential Equations III"

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity, semi-linear-elliptic-pdes

Let $M$ be a bounded domain in $\Bbb R^2$: under the assumption that
$$
\partial_{u} f(x, u)=0 \text { for }|u| \geq K\label{1}\tag{1.6}
$$
Michael E. Taylor said that (proposition (1.3))
For $k=1,2, \ldots$, if $g \in H^{k+1 / 2}(\partial M)$ then any solution $u \in V$ where $V=\left\{u \in H^{1}(M): u=g\right.$ on $\left.\partial M\right\}$ to
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta u &= f(x, u) & \text { on } M \\
u &=g & \text { on } \partial M &
\end{aligned}
$$
belongs to $H^{k+1}(M)$. Hence, if $g \in C^{\infty}(\partial M)$, then $u \in C^{\infty}(\bar{M})$  and $f \in C^{\infty}(\bar{M} \times \mathbb{R})$

**Proof**. We start with $u \in H^{1}(M)$. Then the right side of (1.1) belongs to $H^{1}(M)$ if $f(x, u)$ satisfies \eqref{1}. This gives $u \in H^{2}(M)$, provided $g \in H^{3 / 2}(\partial M)$. Additional regularity follows inductively.

I don't get it: can someone give me some hints?
Actually I don't even know how to prove the right side of (1.1) belongs to $H^{1}(M)$ if $f(x, u)$ satisfies \eqref{1} and $u$ belongs to $H^{1}(M)$.

Comment: If $u\in H^{k}(M)$ then the right hand-side of (1.1) belongs to $H^k$...this gives $u\in H^{K+1}$ etc. (1.6) implies that $\partial_u f(x,u)\in L^\infty$, then apply the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks for answering!But I'm confused that by chain rule, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}(x, u(x))+\partial_{u} f(x, u)$ $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{j}}(x) \in L^{2}(M)$, I know that $\partial_{u} f(x, u) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{j}}(x) \in L^{2}(M)$, but why $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}(x, u(x)) \in L^{2}(M)$

Comment: Because when $u$ is large, $f$ is linear in $u$..

Comment: Are you saying that when $u$ is large, $F$ is linear in $u$($f(x, u)=\partial_{u} F(x, u)$)? Can I say that when $u$ is large, $f$ is independent of $u$? And I'm confused about the relationship between the regularity and the function space $g$ belongs to.

Comment: Since $\partial_u f(x,u)=0$ for $|u|>K$, it is also the case that $\partial_u (\partial_{x_j} f)=0$ for $|u|>K$ (partial derivatives commute as $f$ is smooth). So $$\sup_{M\times\mathbb{R}} \left| \partial_x f\right| = \sup_{M\times[-K-1,K+1]} \left| \partial_x f\right|= \max_{\overline{M}\times[-K-1,K+1]} \left| \partial_x f\right| <\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. With your help, I have understood the proof method of this part of the book. @username